# Javascript onchange function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know this going to be a very basic question, but please be patient with me as I have just started using js and jquery.

Here is my part of code -

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="module.php">
 <select name="dateRange" size="1" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
       <option value > Select Duration </option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1d">Last 24 Hours</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=2d">Last 2 Days</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1w">Last Week</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=2w">Last 2 Weeks</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1m">Last Month</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=3m">Last 3 Months</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=6m">Last 6 Months</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1y">Last Year</option>
       <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=all">All</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now I am not understanding how to write a onchange function where I can do all my query and dispplay my result when user selects any value from the dropdown list. And after that I would like to store the selected value in a variable and use that value in the same page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you give an id called `mySelect` to your select input.

Then you can define:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
    // do your thing
});

</script>
```

The above attaches an `onchange` event (jQuery) to your element and will be triggered every time a user changes the selection.

Comment: I tried doing the same ... I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pooja1110/rxh43/1/)

It runs once and than gives error there.. but on browser it dose not show alert msg and moreover when I select any of the option from the dropdown list it changes the url but again shows "select duration"

Comment: @Satish Are you sure? Your fiddle works perfectly :)

Comment: @Satish Only thing that happens is that your selection fires the value. What exactly do you want to present ?

Comment: no fiddle is not working properly, and atleast with fiddle it is showing alert msg but on browser it does not do that even

Comment: @Satish Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but if you remove this line from select: `onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"` then after every selection the alert pops up and there is no error. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/rxh43/2/

Comment: yes now it works fine even on browser.. this alret msg i was using just to check that whether on selecting any option from drop down list it will show or not. basically i want to write PDO query there and then render graph.

Comment: here how can I store the selected value in use it in a php script ?

Comment: @Satish unfortunately php is outside my scope of expertise, but to get the value you should write `$('#mySelect').val()` where I wrote "do your thing".

Answer (score 1):

you will use a handler

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form method="post" action="module.php">
   <select name="dateRange" size="1" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
      <option value > Select Duration </option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1d">Last 24 Hours</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=2d">Last 2 Days</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1w">Last Week</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=2w">Last 2 Weeks</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1m">Last Month</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=3m">Last 3 Months</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=6m">Last 6 Months</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=1y">Last Year</option>
      <option value="/module.php/?dateRange=all">All</option>
 </select>
</form>

 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

 $( "select" )
    .change(function () {
   alert('OnChange happened');
    //you can add your stuff here
    });
  })

 });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what part is confusing? i tried to create the handler using the same form code given in the question (i guess it will make it easier for the user to understand where / how he can add the handler code), but i can edit it if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

I have created you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxh43/) :)

it uses

```
$('#duration').on('change', function () {
  var selectedEl = $('#duration').val();
    console.log(selectedEl);
});
```

To detect a change in select and `val()` to get the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of this :
   <select name="dateRange" size="1" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
 Try This :
   <select name="dateRange" size="1" onchange="submit();">

And in 'MODULE.php' get the selected value using :
  $var = $_POST['dateRange'];
  echo $var;

And then write your query..
```